# How to enable authors to make posts? (ultimate member)

Tags: wordpress, author, ultimate-member

So I'm making this website in which people(authors) have their profiles and can upload their art works.
I'm using ultimate member plugin and I cannot understand how the author will make posts and post them on their accounts? I mean their is no option to create posts! and the plugin documentation is not helping I have already followed it but there is still no option/button for the authors to make and publish posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+new exists on the admin bar. from there you can add media or text!
[image]